# Prove that $\| BC\| \leq \| B\|\| C\|$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have problem with this:
$$\| BC\| \leq \| B\|\| C\|$$
where $\|\cdot\|$ means spectral norm defined as $$\|A\|=\text{max}\lbrace\|Ax\|:x\in\mathbb{C^n, \|x\|=1}\rbrace$$ 
where the norms on the are according to standard scalar product.

For my homework I had to solve $\|A+B\|\leq\|A\|+\|B\|$ which I managed to do by myself but this second inequality seems to be (at least for me) much harder. Any ideas?

Comment: My edits bring this closer to standart MathJax and LaTeX usage.  Notice in particular \cdot. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: I have already seen it - thx

Comment: What you say you have to show for your homework seems false as the two sides scale differenly. Maybe you meant $||A || + ||B||$.

Comment: Thx, I corrected it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recall (or prove) that $||Ay|| \le ||A|| \ ||y||$ for every $y$.

Then, apply this twice to get,  $$||BCx||  \le   ||B|| \ ||Cx|| \le ||B|| \ ||C|| \ ||x||.$$

Comment: Exist such a nice trick for the inequality \|A+B\|\leq\|A\|+\|B\|? Because I proved that using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality - and that is not as short as this nice proof :-)

Comment: Yes. Do $$||(A+ B)x ||=||Ax+ Bx || \le ||Ax|| + ||Bx || \le ||A||||x|| + ||B||||x || = (||A||+ ||B||) ||x||, $$ where the first inequality is triangle ineqauilty for the vector norm.

Comment: That is much neater than mine. Thanks a lot